# Why do negative logic gates require a bias in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-operations, neural-networks

I was doing some research about the simplest neural network that can model each logic gate. By simplest I mean:

- no bias if possible
- fewest number of layers
- fewest number of neurons in each layer
- no activation function if possible

Starting from a 1-neuron network with no bias, I came up with the following chart:

[image]

I noticed that all the "negated" gates, namely NOT, NOR, NAND, and XNOR  need a bias. Also note those gates are the negations of IDENTITY, OR, AND and XOR respectively.

1) Is this observation true?

2) If it is, why does "negation" require a bias?

Rigorous proofs and intuitive explanations are both welcome.

***Edit***: since there seems to be some confusion about what architecture/type of network I am referring too, I am adding a link showing diagrams of what I have found are the corresponding "simplest neural networks":

http://onehoursreflection.blogspot.com/2017/06/summary-of-simplest-neural-nets-for.html

Comment: Explain how only a bias is needed for a NOT gate,  `0 + bias = 1` and `1 + bias = 0` does not make sense. You need to use a weight in there at least ( I don't see you mentioning weights anywere?)

Comment: Of course you need weights... I never said you were only using a bias...

Comment: It is unclear. $minus(x)= -x, x \in \mathbb{R}$ is linear so a single linear neuron is sufficient. $not(x) = -x, x\in \{-1,1\}$ is  also linear. $or(x,y), (x,y) \in \{-1,1\}$  is non-linear : you need a non-linear (sigmoid) neuron with a bias. The same for $and(x,y)$.  $xor(x,y) = or(and(x,-y),and(-x,y))$ needs 3 non-linear neurons (2 layers) @ThomasW